# Minecraft commands aren't working for me

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to get rid of all the bats in my Minecraft world, but the command`/kill @e[type=Bat]` isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

If the commands aren't working and you are sure that it is correct (The one on your question is correct), then either you have cheats disabled, you aren't op (only if you're on servers), or using an old version. The "@e" target selector was added in Minecraft 1.8.0.

Comment: I forgot the name for @e @a etc., feel free to edit if you know. Also it might be mods causing some commands stop working.

Comment: Questioner doesn't know how to enable cheats.

Comment: @ardaozkal: They're types of [target selector](https://gist.github.com/Dinnerbone/3736487).

Answer (score 0):

The command looks correct for 1.12. If that is the version that you are using, try enabling cheats of it is *your* world and if it's a server that belongs to a friend, get them to do `/op yourmcusername`. If you are on a server like hive or mineplex, you can't do commands like that.

Hope this helped,
DM01131